# Eclipse MySQL JDBC driver setup not register driver class

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jdbc, birt

Add JDBC Database Connection for Query Builder in Eclipse BIRT Data Explorer:

1. Choose "JDBC Database Connection for Query Builder".
2. Choose "MySQL" as connection profile.
3. Still no MySQL driver. No problem, add connector external jar for MySQL 5.1. Configure other parameters for data source. Tested ok.

That's it. I can use this data source to use data sets.

Next one.

Instead of previously successfully used "JDBC Database Connection for Query Builder" I want to use more flexible "JDBC Data Source". Oops, I see that hasn't driver class for MySQL - only 2 default entries for Derby and Sample.

Seems valid registration of JDBC driver doesn't add (or register?) driver class.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the jar file of the JDBC driver under

```
   [eclipse home]\plugins\org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc[version number]\drivers
```

Then restart Eclipse and Mysql will be available in the list of JDBC datasources. As you mentionned a "JDBC datasource" is much more flexible, i highly recommend to use it instead of "JDBC database for connection builder".